# Дано целое положительное число "target". Также дана последовательность из целых положительных чисел. Необходимо записать в выходной файл "1", если

Tags: python, python-3.x

Условие задачи: дано целое положительное число "target". Также дана последовательность из целых положительных чисел. Необходимо записать в выходной файл "1", если в последовательности есть два числа, сумма которых равна значению "target" или "0", если таких нет. Число "target" и последовательность берутся из файла "input.txt".
Моё решение ниже.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
target, sequence = [x for x in input_file.read().split('\n')]
amounts = [[int(x) + int(y) for y in sequence.split()] for x in sequence.split()]
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for item in amounts:
        if int(target) in item:
            output_file.write('1')
            break
        else:
            output_file.write('0')
            break
```

Пример входных данных в файле "input.txt":
5
1 7 3 4 7 9
Вопрос: можно ли решить эту задачу другим способом, или максимально оптимизировать моё решение (хотелось бы увидеть код)?
Заранее, благодарю.

Comment: Добавьте пример файла `input.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Если обернуть код в функцию, то можно выходить из нескольких
# вложенных циклов с помощью return
def find_target(in_file):
    target, sequence = in_file.read().splitlines()
    # Преобразуем данные в нужный тип заранее - не стоит делать этого в цикле
    target = int(target)
    sequence = list(map(int, sequence.split()))

    # На каждой итерации берём число 'a'
    for idx, a in enumerate(sequence):
        # и по очереди складываем его с каждым числом находящимся правее.
        # Числа находящиеся левее уже проверены в предыдущих итерациях
        for b in sequence[idx + 1:]:
            if target == (a + b):
                return 1
    return 0

# Открываем сразу два файла
with open("input.txt") as in_file, open("output.txt", 'w') as out_file:
    # Использую функцию print(), так как она печатает в файл с переводом строки 
    print(find_target(in_file), file=out_file)
```

**input.txt**

```
15
4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов Исправил.

Answer (score 5):

Можно решить за `O(n)`.

Создаем словарь с количеством вхождений каждого числа за `O(n)`. Проходимся по всем элементам словаря и проверяем есть ли в словаре элемент `target - текущий элемент`.
Если есть, то надо проверить, что это не тот же самый элемент, если тот же самый, то он нам подходит, только, если встречается более одного раза.

Проверка это `O(1)`, проход по всем элементам словаря это `O(n)`.
По итогу имеем `O(n) + O(n) => O(n)`.

```
from collections import Counter

your_data = [5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6]
target = 10

data_counter = Counter(your_data)

for i in data_counter:
    if target - i in data_counter and (i != target - i or data_counter[target - i] > 1):
        print (i, target - i)
        break
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/6lYNDm)